# How to increase debugger output in lldb?

Tags: c++, macos, lldb

I'm trying to use lldb to print a very large vector in C++. I do `p/x <my vector>` to see its content.

My problem is that lldb truncates the output adding an ellipsis at the end. How can I make it print the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum number of elements (lldb calls these "children") printed when printing a vector or other collection is controlled by a setting:

```
(lldb) set show target.max-children-count
target.max-children-count (int) = 256
```

You can up the maximum with the settings set command, like:

```
(lldb) set set target.max-children-count 1024
```

If you want lldb to always print all the elements set this to -1.  There's a bit of a trick to that, since "-1" looks like a command option, so you have to tell lldb that it isn't an option using the "--" argument like:

```
(lldb) set set -- target.max-children-count -1
```

The "--" is not specific to this command, but is a general feature of lldb...

You can put this in your ~/.lldbinit file to have it set in all lldb sessions.

Comment: I get an error at the lldb console in XCode that 'set' is ambiguous and can be settings, setinput and settext, so it's probably worth revising your answer to change the first 'set' to 'settings'.

Comment: Neither `setinput` nor `settext` are built in lldb commands.  Probably you are getting the version that comes with Chisel?  I try to show short forms of commands so people learn that they don't need to type them out in full.  It is always possible to add commands to an lldb session that make built-in ones ambiguous, but I still think showing shorter commands that work with the default lldb set is worthwhile despite that fact.  Also, `set` is such a common command, I'd think twice before adding a user command that renders it ambiguous...